# Can't not build ixgbe of meta-intel

Tags: yocto

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += “ ixgbe ixgbevf"
```

when building the image, it shows:

```
....ixgbevf-4.6.3/src/kcompat.h 2766:10, fatal error, linux/pci-aspm.h no such file
```

I am using meta-intel.

Comment: which version of kernel are you using `linux/pci-aspm.h` is not available in kernel newer than 4.19

Comment: I am using default yocto kernel, it is 5.4.20, any method to resolve it? I build from source, it says it needs kernel-header, how to add it?

Comment: 5.4 might need different way. try 4.19